# What multinlingual database support for Django 1.3?

Tags: python, django, orm, multilingual, django-multilingual

I am using Django for quite a while but each time I ask myself the same question again and again.

Which multilingual database backend should I use ?

I used `django-multilingual` on Django 1.1, `django-multilingual-ng` on Django 1.2

I add a look at `django-nani` for Django 1.3 but there quite few problems :

- No [ModelAdmin API support](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-nani/en/latest/public/admin.html#modeladmin-apis-not-available-on-translatableadmin) :
- I cannot modify the TranslatedFields on the save() method since the object is created by a post_signal after.

I which some people overthere could help me find a way to handle multilingual websites.

I like the way multilingual, multilingual-ng and nani handle languages in the admin with tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution is to use this projet that is made by the creator of django-multilingual-ng (
[django-hvad](https://github.com/KristianOellegaard/django-hvad) )
but the probleme is that it's in alpha state.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look a these ressource pages:

- [Django Packages Model translation](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-translation/)
- [Django Packages Internationalization](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/i18n/)
- [Django Wiki Model Internationalization](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ModelInterNationalization)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at django-transmeta

http://code.google.com/p/django-transmeta/